# How to deploy PHP project with Bamboo?

Tags: php, deployment, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have a simple php project on github.
And I want to set up Continuous Integration with Bamboo.

**Step 1:**
I've set up "Plan" with "Default Job".
"Default Job" has just one task: Source Code Checkout.

**Step 1.1:**
After run **build** I see the source code in */Users/serhiit/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/LOCPR-WEB-JOB1*.

**Step 2:**
Also I've set up "Deploy" with just one task: Clean working directory task.

**Step 2.1:**
After run **deploy** I see the empty folder */Users/serhiit/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/786434-851970*.

**Question:**
How can I move my code to directory */var/www/myproject*?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to create ZIP Artifact, upload it to your server and unzip it.

**Step 1**: Add new task to your default job - "Script", and inside body add a zip command to create zip file out of your code.

**Step 2**: Go to Artifacts tab, and define your artifact. Make sure to Share this artifact.

**Step 3**: Add new tasks to your Deploy - first Artifact download, and select your new created artifact.

**Step 4**: Add new task - SCP task. It will allow you to copy your zip file to your server. Specify your server credentials and remote path.

**Step 5**: Add new task - SSH task. Add a simple unzip command to unpack your files.